# Configure Adsense and Google Analytics to consistently use ascending date format in reports

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-adsense, date-format

This might not be a big issue for some, but it bugs me a lot.

The date format for google **Adsense**, **Analytics** and **AdMob** is M/dd/YYYY eg. **Feb 1 2017**.
In some reports the date is **mm/dd/yyyy** eg. **01/02/2017**..

I want to have the date in **dd/M/YYYY** eg. **1 Feb 2017**

I was not able to find any such setting.

This throws me off every time as in my country and in my day-to-day life I am used to seeing dates in ascending order.